# new to mac and textmate, can someone explain these shortcuts?

Tags: python, textmate

I'm using textmate for the first time basically, and I am lost as to what keys map to these funny symbols.

using python bundles, what keys do I press for:

run
run with tests
run project unit tests

Also, with textmate, do I actually define a project in textmate or do I just work on the files and textmate doesn't create its own .project type file ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out this [link](https://www.osxkeyboardshortcuts.com/keyboard-symbols.html) for some of the translations to some of the keyboard symbols. This should help you out :)

Also [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236) is a link from the Apple site for an exhaustive list of shortcuts.

[image]
<sub>(source: [osxkeyboardshortcuts.com](http://www.osxkeyboardshortcuts.com/keyboard-symbols_files/apple-keyboard-symbols.png))</sub>

Answer (score 2):

> Also, with textmate, do I actually define a project in textmate or do I just work on the files and textmate doesn't create its own .project type file ?

You can do both. You can create a new project in TextMate by going to File -> New Project and add your files manually, or you can drag a folder into TextMate and it will create a project from those files (you can add other files later). Note that the second method will not create a `.tmproj` file, though, so if you want to "keep" that project, you'll have to save it (File -> Save Project).